# Contacts custom field of FILE type- how to search if file attached?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I created a custom field type of FILE and it does have Searchable=YES but it does not come up as an option to search in Advanced Search.

I am trying to list contacts that have a file attached to this file type field (versus contacts that have not had a file attached).

Note that the other custom fields in the field set appear in the Advanced search, but not the File one.

Is this possible to search like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use SearchKit to search for entities where your field Is Empty or Not Empty.

For Advanced Search, I don't think you should be able to set searchable on a File custom field. Isn't the searchable option hidden when you choose Data Type = File?

Comment: It does have the SEARCHABLE column with Yes/No option under Custom Data Fields for the Data Type=file with Field Type=file.

Comment: See what you, looks like a bug, you shouldn't be able to change that. But this will be replaced with a new display in the not too distant future, so probably not worth fixing.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this issue, I was able to use Contact Reports then Constituent Summary and then I could choose the customn fields, including the FILE field, as an option in the report, and then I sorted on that File field to pull up all the contacts with a file attached.